# Extract mapping from LINQ in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my datamodel I have

Market -> Customers

Market contains about 10 records and Customers several million records.

In my CustomerDTO-object I have Market with No of Customers.

Today I fill the CustomerDTO-object like this:

```
  using (var ctx = new Data.MyEntities())
            {
                var markets = ctx.Market_TB
                                    .Include(m => m.MarketStatus_TB)
                                    .Select(m => new MarketDTO
                                                     {
                                                         Description = m.Description
                                                         StatusDate = m.StatusDate,
                                                         ID = m.IDMarket,
                                                         Status = m.MarketStatus_TB.Description,
                                                         Volume = m.Customer_TB.Count()
                                                     }
                                    ).ToList();


                return markets;
            }
```

But I really would like to do the mapping somewhere else. I obviously don't want to get all the Customer Enteties from the DB just to count them. Perhaps it's just Friday afternoon and I don't see the obvious. I'm considering a stored procedure, but I rather not.

Comment: So what's the question?  What do you want to be able to do?

Comment: `m.Customer_TB.Count()` doesn't get all the customers, unless you're using some evil voodoo implementation in your context.

Comment: LOL... I'd like to map it outside the LINQ expression. But I don't see how. 

I'd like to do something like ctx.Market.Include(m => m.Customer.Count());

Comment: And then something like: var returnvalue = Mapper.Map<Entity, DTO>(markets);